# Sorting Data of a GET request from an fake rest api (npm json-server) by creation time reverse

Tags: json-server

I created a fake Rest API with JSON-Server for my todo app.
Is it possible to sort the data by creation time. so that the latest todos appear in first place

Answer (score 0):

[JSON Server Sorting](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#sort) is probably what you're looking for.

Something like this:

`/todos?_sort=createTime&_order=desc`